# Is it possible to upload a file to dropbox when user is not logged in?

Tags: php, dropbox

I am developing a web application for my company. Every employee in the company has a dropbox account. Is it possible to send a file to everyone's dropbox account? I want to send files to employee's dropbox instead of sending mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Aside from the shared folder option mentioned by @Tabish, you can also use the API to write to each user's Dropbox. To do this, you will need an access token for each user, which you get when that user authorizes your app. You can store these access tokens and use them later without any further interaction from the user.

So it's a two-step process:

1. Have each user authorize the app, and store their access tokens.
2. Write files to each user's Dropbox by authenticating with each user's stored access token.

Answer (score -1):

Yes u can share files with other employees. but you have to add account of ur employees in shared folder and set default upload file location is that shared folder only.